# How to select rows from a table based on a column value in another table that has multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

**User** with columns UserId, Area

The `Area` column is populated with multiple comma separated values (from listbox) - data looks like this:

```
User1 KA,TN,AP,GJ
User2 MH,UP,MP,GJ
```

**Order** with columns OrderID, ProductID, Qty, Area

Data looks like this:

```
1 Prod1 10 GJ
2 Prod1 22 MH
3 Prod2 3  AP
4 Prod2 77 TN
```

How to select rows from `Order` table based on `User` table?

Say logged in user is `User1`. His areas are `KA,TN,AP,GJ`.

The result should look like this:

```
Prod1 10 GJ
Prod2 77 TN
```

Please advise on the SQL query to get this result.

Thanks and regards
Krishna

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if your data was normalized.  Why are you storing multiple values as one string blob in a single field?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is **Absolutly yes!**

Comment: why the 3rd record is missing in the result set ? Area 'AP' is also linked to 'User1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set this solution as a good practice because *as all comments said above*:
Never, ever store data as comma separated items.

**Workaround:-**

Manipulate the values that selected form `user` table for getting a good structure via using `Replace` function as next demo:-

```
Create table #user (username varchar(10), Areas varchar (100))
go
insert into #user values ('User1', 'KA,TN,AP,GJ')
insert into #user values ('User2', 'MH,UP,MP,GJ')
go
Create table #order ( OrderID int , ProductID varchar(10), Qty int , Area char (2))
go
insert into #order values (1, 'Prod1', 10, 'GJ')
insert into #order values (2, 'Prod1', 22, 'MH')
insert into #order values (3, 'Prod2', 3,  'AP')
insert into #order values (4, 'Prod2', 77, 'TN')
go 

declare @List nvarchar(250)

select @List = '('''+(select Areas from #user where username = 'User1') + ''')'
select @List = replace(@List,',',''',''')


exec ('select ProductID,Qty, area from #order
where Area in' +  @List )

drop table #user
drop table #order
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Note: I assumed the 3rd record is missing in your desired result set by mistake.

Comment: @nkrishna Glad to help you, bro :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `patindex`

```
select o.*
from u
join o on patindex('%,'+o.Area+',%', ','+u.area+',')>0
where userid= 'User1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Store data as comma separated items is not a good practice.
But you can try something like below

```
DECLARE @V_USER NVARCHAR(100)   ='User1'

SELECT  *
FROM    Order   AS  O
    INNER JOIN User AS U    ON U.Area LIKE '%'+O.Area+'%'
WHERE   U.UserId    =   @V_USER
```